# hadoop native library only shows up with sudo

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I'm trying to set up hadoop and put in all the `env` variables in my `bashrc` on an **Ubuntu**. The problem is if I do the following in a terminal,

```
hadoop checknative
```

I get the response:

```
14/07/23 01:48:10 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your    platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Native library checking:
hadoop: false
zlib:   false
snappy: false
lz4:    false
bzip2:  false
```

but if I use `sudo`

```
sudo hadoop/bin/hadoop checknative
```

I get the response:

```
14/07/23 01:48:36 WARN bzip2.Bzip2Factory: Failed to load/initialize native-bzip2 library system-    native, will use pure-Java version
14/07/23 01:48:36 INFO zlib.ZlibFactory: Successfully loaded & initialized native-zlib library
Native library checking:
hadoop: true /home/ubuntu/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0
zlib:   true /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
snappy: false
lz4:    true revision:99
bzip2:  false
```

What should I do so I see the libraries without sudo? Am I going to have to use root always?

Comment: Try: chown -R yourusername /hadoop/bin/hadoop if you want to run as youself.

Comment: Also, see this, which explains how to run as root, but without a password. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt by changing sudoers entry.

Comment: i already took ownership of the whole hadoop dir. it didn't change anything.

Comment: i shouldn't have to run it as root. plus all the guides that i've followed didn't use sudo for running hadoop.

Comment: i also applied `chmod 770`

Comment: this post is not a duplicate. i am aware of the problem with a 64bit linux . the ubuntu was 32 bit. furthermore, it doesn't explain why it just works with sudo.